# Can we use UISearchBar in tvOS?

Tags: uisearchbar, tvos

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html) indicates that `UISearchBar` is available to us in tvOS (and Apple certainly uses it in their Search view) but I can't find it in the Object Library.

Is anyone else having the same problem? I haven't seen a single post or comment about it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UIKitCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple tvOS documentation and find SearchViewController.swift. You have to initialize an UISearchController and present it.

Comment: The link has a sample project that can be downloaded was extremely helpful in showing how to use UI elements in tvOS including UISearchController

Comment: Can I implement UISearchController without present it in TVOS.

Comment: I have implemented UISearchController in Tabbar item but search bar hide under the tabbar . How to fix this issue. Please suggest it.

Comment: @vipulk617 Hi have you implemented UISearchController in tabbar ?

Comment: I have implemented UISearchController in tabbar but not working properly.

Comment: Does anyone have a working code for SearchBar that they can post? This Apple sample project is insane.

Answer (score 1):

There are no search bar related items in the object library for tvOS, so you can't  put a `UISearchBar` in a storyboard or XIB..

So far, the only way to get a `UISearchBar` is by code, using the one provided by `UISearchController`. The `UISearchController` instance has either to presented (like in the UIKitCatalog example) or to be embedded using a `UISearchContainerViewController` (for example in a `UITabBarController`)

Comment: I have implemented UISearchController in Tabbar item but search bar hide under the tabbar . How to fix this issue. Please suggest it.

Comment: Hi, I searched a lot for presenting UisearchController in same class instead of presenting it. Is that possible like what youtube does to show search in same controller using Tabbar?